# Self-student variational calculus - the maxima and minima simplest problem

Tags: examples-counterexamples, self-learning, maxima-minima, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

I am starting a self-taught study in Variational Calculus. The first thing I see in every book is the Euler-Lagrange equation.

However, what comes to my mind as the first and simplest question of Variational Calculus would be maxima and minima of a function. So I would expect the result of the derivative to be $0$ at the maxima and minima to be a particular result of the Euler-Lagrange equations.

But, I couldn't find this example anywhere (maybe because it's too simple).

Can you help me? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, that's it. The Euler-Lagrange equations are exactly the statement that the derivative vanishes at an extremizer.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro, please, could you explain more detailed how can I derive the result of the classical calculus maxima and minima from EL equation? I'll happy to bount you tomorrow, when the system allows. Something like "From this functional and this equation, if we consider XXXX, we recover the classical result...". I am stucked. Thank you in advance

Comment: You have it the wrong way around @Quiet_waters. The Euler-Lagrange equations are the result of the fact that differentiable functions are zero at a local minimum/maximum within an open set, not the other way around. Those equations are what you can derive if you look at the zeroes of the derivative of the action functional.

Comment: @ManateePink thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Euler-Lagrange equation for the functional $F\colon X\to \mathbb R$, where $X$ is a Banach space, is given by
$$
F'(x)=0, $$
where $F'$ is the Fréchet derivative of $F$. Now, what is the Fréchet derivative? It is something that we do not need to define, many books are devoted to that. What we need to do is to observe that, when $X=\mathbb R$ (which is a Banach space), the Fréchet derivative reduces to the ordinary derivative of a function of one real variable. Therefore the Euler-Lagrange equation reduces to the familiar statement of calculus that a derivative must vanish at maxima and minima of a function.

**ADDED**. The comments argue that this answer does not really address the question. So, let me explain how does $F'(x_\star)=0$ follow from $x_\star$ being a maximizer for $F$. Note that the opposite statement does NOT hold; there is no way to prove that $x_\star$ is a maximizer by looking only at $F'$.  So, if the question is about that, the answer is a simple "no".

Suppose that $x_\star$ is a maximizer; this means that, however you take an $x\in X$, the incremental ratio
$$\tag{1}
\frac{F(x_\star + t x)-F(x_\star)}{t}
$$
is nonnegative for $t>0$ and nonpositive for $t<0$. This follows at once from observing that $F(x_\star + t x)\ge F(x_\star)$, since $x_\star$ is a maximizer.

Now, since $F$ is differentiable, the incremental ratio (1) has a limit as $t\to 0$. By the considerations above, this limit must be both nonnegative and nonpositive. So the limit is $0$, which concludes the proof.

Comment: I think this is the wrong answer. As far as I understood, OP wanted to know if and how the fact that the derivative of a differentiable function is zero at a minimum/maximum is a result of the Euler-Lagrange equations. However, it is exactly the other way around, those equations are a result of the zero derivative fact. And as far as I know and can tell, you can't go both ways, the equations after all are only applicable to a certain class of functionals.

Comment: @ManateePink: Of course, the functionals must be differentiable, otherwise you cannot even speak of a Fréchet derivative. The other point you make is unclear to me. I will add a bit of clarification in the text to try and convince you to revert the downvote. Thank you for your message, this is how downvote should be.

Comment: Thx for the great reply. Your edit is great as well, but it just doesn't address the issue. Look at a comment by OP, following excerpt "From this functional and this equation, if we consider XXXX, we recover the classical result...". I believe what they actually want to know is if for some arbitrary differentiable function $f$ you can construct some functional (or smth like that) which you apply the Euler-Lagrange equations to in such a way so that it follows that the derivative of $f$ at a local maximum/minimum is $0$. @Quiet_waters can you confirm or deny this,please?

Comment: More compactly written, I believe they want to know if $\text{The maximizer/minimizer of an action potential satisfies the Euler-Lagrange equations} \implies \text{The derivative of any differentiable function is zero at a local minimum/maximum}$ holds.

Comment: So in other words the question is whether the Euler-Lagrange equations coincide with the equations of vanishing of a derivative. but this is essentially just a matter of naming things, it is impossible to answer if the OP does not give their definition of Euler-Lagrange equations.

Comment: @ManateePink, yes, it was exactly what I was thinking: if for some arbitrary differentiable function $f$ you can construct some functional (or smth like that) which you apply the Euler-Lagrange equations to in such a way so that it follows that the derivative of f at a local maximum/minimum is $0$.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I am afraid that I could not explain very well. But I think the comments above can translate my thought: given the Euler-Lagrange  equation (https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_Euler-Lagrange), I'd like to know if there's some functional for which the equations can give us the statement $f'(x^\star)=0$. Your answer and so the sequence of comments gave me the ideia that the E-L equations are derived from $f'(x^\star)=0$, not an "extension" of it. Am I right?

Comment: @Quiet_waters: I have a hard time understanding your doubt, because for me, the Euler-Lagrange equation is EXACTLY the equation $f'(x)=0$. So I cannot understand how you can derive one from the other; they are the same thing.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro, sorry by that. But now the things are more clear to me. Thank you two!